# RegEx to replace text between dollar signs

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to use C# .NET to replace every instance of text between dollar signs. For example:

```
Check out this TeX: $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. It's cool.
```

...becomes...

```
Check out this TeX: <img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=x\in\mathbb{Z}^%2B" alt="x\in\mathbb{Z}^+" />. It's cool.
```

Note that the formula needs to be URL encoded before it is passed to the Google Charts API.

Please could you show me how to do this using RegEx (or otherwise)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the overload of `Regex.Replace`, that accepts a delegate that computes the replacement:

```
private string GetCodeForTex(Match match)
{
    string tex = match.Groups[1].Value;
    return string.Format(
        "<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"{1}\" />", GetEscapedUrlForTex(tex), tex);
}

…

Regex.Replace(textWithDollars, @"\$([^\$]*)\$", GetCodeForTex);
```

Your code in `GetCodeForTex` might be different (and you might think of a better name for it), but I'm sure you get the idea.

Also, be careful with simple parsing using regexes like this. It means you can never use `$` for anything else than enclosing TeX. And the result will be mess if you have unclosed `$` somewhere in the input text.

Comment: Thanks. What format would you suggest I use instead of $tex$ ?

Comment: There's no simple answer for that. Especially considering you might want to use `$` (or any other simple delimiter you choose) inside the TeX code. Truly robust solution would be to implement actual parser for your format. Or, since it looks you're in HTML environment, you could use existing HTML parsers and use something like `<math>text code</math>`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example method that will work for you. Note that by using the `Regex.Matches` method, the method is able to handle multiple matches at once:

```
public static string AddImgTags(string input)
{
   string pattern = @"\$([^\$]*)\$";

   foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
   {
      input = input.Replace(match.Value, 
         string.Format("<img src=\"http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl={0}\" alt=\"{0}\" />", 
         HttpUtility.UrlEncode(match.Value)));
   }

   return input;
}
```

An explanation of the pattern ("`\$[^\$]*\$`") is as follows:

- `\$` - Matches the beginning `$`
- `([^\$]*)` - Matches any character except for `$`, repeated 0 or more times. Also groups the matching characters so that they can be referenced later.
- `\$` - Matches the ending `$`

Comment: Thanks. What should 'replacement' look like? The difficulty is that the text between the dollar signs needs to be URL encoded before it is passed to the image url.

Comment: I think you can't use this method, when the replacement has to contain *modified* version of the captured text.

Comment: @James Take a look at the updated version, it has the ability to handle multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

The general regex would be

```
 var s = Regex.Replace("test $blabla$! It worked", @"\$.*?\$", "123");
```

`s` will become `"test 123! It worked"`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers would do a simple replace, but they don't grab the group, and place it in your replacement.

So, start with @Donut's Reg Ex, with a tiny change to add a capture group

`\$([^\$]*)\$`

The other change is to call Regex.Match, so you can grab the text inside the `$` using [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx).Captures.  Then you can run the URL encoding on it to build the Replacement text.

Something like:

```
var urlTemplate = "<img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl={0}" alt="{1}" />";
var matchText = match.Captures[0].Value;

var url = string.Format(urlTemplate, UrlEncode(matchText), matchText);
```

Since you know exactly what the text is now, you can just do a normal replace for this instance, and then loop to find the rest of the matches

Comment: What if there is more than one substring that needs replacing?

Comment: Also, your regex is wrong. You want to have that `*` outside of the `[]` character group.

Comment: Opps on the regex - as I said I just took it from @Donut, since he didn't address the URL encoding during replacement.  Thanks for the info about taking the delegate, I wasn't aware of it.