# Java - RegEx to replace text between dollar signs

Tags: java, regex

I am using JAVA and want to replace every instance of text between dollar signs. For example:

```
1st equation $\frac{1}{\mu -1}\frac{2\pi }{\lambda }x$ 
2nd equation $90^{^{0}}$
3rd equation $\frac{\mu t}{2}$
4th equation $2\mu tcosr=\frac{\left ( 2n+1 \right ) \lambda}{2}$
```

to be replaced by this

```
1st equation <img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$\frac{1}{\mu -1}\frac{2\pi }{\lambda }x$ " border="0"/>
2nd equation <img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$90^{^{0}}$" border="0"/>
3rd equation <img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$\frac{\mu t}{2}$" border="0"/>
4th equation <img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$2\mu tcosr=\frac{\left ( 2n+1 \right ) \lambda}{2}$" border="0"/>
```

i searched on stackoverflow.com and found something similar for C#.NET [RegEx to replace text between dollar signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666305/regex-to-replace-text-between-dollar-signs)

Comment: Double escape the `$` like `\\$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it would be something like this...

```
myString.replaceAll("\\$[^$]*\\$", 
     "<img src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$0 \" border=\"0\"/>"
```

The `$0` in the replacement string should match the capturing group in the search regex per...

[String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

[Matcher.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: You don't need to escape the the dollar sign inside the character class. Also, you can remove the parentheses, if you're not using `$1` anyway. Finally, note that this does not take care of escaped `$` in the input string. And this can cause invalid HTML if the match contains `"` - but that's a problem of the OP's approach, I think.

Comment: Good points (updated) however WRT `escaped $`, to what are you referring.

Comment: Something like `$this\$should\$only\$give\$one\$match$`

Comment: So you are assuming that this might be a valid input string. I don't see that in the example. However, if it is possible the OP must take it into consideration.

Comment: It's valid LaTeX after all. I also didn't mean to say your solution is flawed. I just wanted it to be there for the OPs information.

Comment: I am ignorant of Latex. Will defer to your better knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The regex used in C# is the same for Java, except that you need to double escape `$`.

```
"\\$([^\\$]*)\\$"
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, but i want the exact code to iterate for each instance.

Comment: I understand but I think this is enough if you know how to use regexes in Java. I'm not going to give you the code to copy-paste it, sorry ;)

Comment: i was not asking for the code to copy-paste, i was not sure how to refer to the matched group. for e.g. `$0`

Comment: Oh I see, you didn't specify that in your comment. I think JohnB's answer already shows you how to use.