# regex to replace text *outside* of {}

Tags: r, regex, latex, notepad++, bookdown

I want to use regex to replace commands or tags around strings. My use case is converting LaTeX commands to bookdown commands, which means doing things like replacing `\citep{*}` with `[@*]`, `\ref{*}` with `\@ref(*)`, etc. However, lets stick to the generalized question:

Given a string `<begin>somestring<end>` where `<begin>` and `<end>` are known  and `somestring` is an arbitrary sequence of characters, can we use regex to susbstitute `<newbegin>` and `<newend>` to get the string `<newbegin>somestring<newend>`?

For example, consider the LaTeX command `\citep{bonobo2017}`, which I want to convert to `[@bonobo2017]`. For this example:

```
<begin> = \citep{
somestring = bonobo2017
<end> = }
<newbegin> = [@
<newend> = ]
```

This question is basically the inverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397720/java-regex-to-replace-text-between-dollar-signs).

I'm hoping for an R or notepad++ solution.

**Additional Examples**

1. Convert `\citet{bonobo2017}` to `@bonobo2017`
2. Convert `\ref{myfigure}` to `\@ref(myfigure)`
3. Convert `\section{Some title}` to `# Some title`
4. Convert `\emph{something important}` to `*something important*`

I'm looking for a template regex that I can fill in my `<begin>`, `<end>`, `<newbegin>` and `<newend>` on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: `(\\.*?{)(.*?)(})` replace with `[@\2]`? If you post multiple examples we can better find you a solution

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels, I have added some examples. Can you post your comment as an answer with some explanation? I have used regex before but only for fairly simple cases. These look like regex groups to me, which I have not used before. Does `\2` refer to the index of a group in the regex string?

Comment: There may be better options than my answer, but if you're looking for a magical "do everything" regex, that's only possible through a hack since you can't make replacements conditional in regex. [See here for hack](https://regex101.com/r/szg5xq/1). This method appends a dictionary to the document and uses the dictionary values as replacements. See this website for more information about its use: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-conditional-replacement.html When you're done, remove the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels, I think I have few enough commands that I can use useR's solution, but others may find the dictionary approach very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this with `dplyr` + `stringr`:

```
string = "\\citep{bonobo2017}"

begin = "\\citep{"
somestring = "bonobo2017"
end = "}"
newbegin = "[@"
newend = "]"

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

string %>%
  str_extract(paste0("(?<=\\Q", begin, "\\E)\\w+(?=\\Q", end, "\\E)")) %>%
  paste0(newbegin, ., newend)
```

or:

```
string %>%
  str_replace_all(paste0("\\Q", begin, "\\E|\\Q", end, "\\E"), "") %>%
  paste0(newbegin, ., newend)
```

You can also make it a function for convenience:

```
convertLatex = function(string, BEGIN, END, NEWBEGIN, NEWEND){
  string %>%
    str_replace_all(paste0("\\Q", BEGIN, "\\E|\\Q", END, "\\E"), "") %>%
    paste0(NEWBEGIN, ., NEWEND)
}

convertLatex(string, begin, end, newbegin, newend)

# [1] "[@bonobo2017]"
```

**Notes:**

- Notice that I manually added an additional `\` to `"\\citep{bonobo2017}"`, this is because raw strings don't exist in R(I hope they do exist), so a single `\` would be treated as an escape character. I need another `\` to escape the first `\`.
- The regex in `str_extract` uses positive lookbehind and positve lookahead to extract the `somestring` in between `begin` and `end`.
- `str_replace` takes another approach of removing `begin` and `end` from `string`.
- The `"\\Q"`, `"\\E"` pair in the regex means "Backslash all nonalphanumeric characters" and `"\\E"` ends the expression. This is especially useful in your case since you likely have special characters in your Latex command. This expression automatically escapes them for you.

Comment: Thanks @useR, this looks really promising. Can you explain what is happening with `(?<=\\Q` ... `\\E)` and `\\E|\\Q ... \\E)`? The first one almost looks like a zero-length assertion but that can't be right.

Comment: @mikeck Added some notes, see if this explains things a little better.

Comment: Thanks @useR, I think this will work. I can combine your function with `str_detect` calls to extract all instances of a given command (e.g. `\citep{*}`) and replace it with the bookdown equivalent (e.g. `[@*]`).