# how to get list of values(sub string) between $$ in from a string

Tags: java

I need to get the list of strings a string encoded between $$.
for example, 
I have a string in Java as below

String st = Dear Mr $person_name$, Your current status is $current_status$.

how can i get the list using regex such as 
list = {person_name,current_status}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regex to replace text between dollar signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397720/java-regex-to-replace-text-between-dollar-signs)

Comment: Sir, I need the subStrings without dollar signs while the link shared by your are using the regex which returning the subString with the dollar sign

Comment: Please show what you have tried, otherwise no one is going to even try to help. Please take the [tour], go through the [help], learn [ask] and post a proper [mcve] as code-formatted text that we can copy-paste and see the same behavior as you

Answer (score 0):

You may use `"\\$.*?\\$"` pattern to match the substring that starts and ends with `$`.
Then, just remove `$`, and add to list.

```
String text = "test $test1$ test2 $test3$ test4 test5 $test6$";

List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();

String patternString = "\\$.*?\\$";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0).replace("$", ""));
    strList.add(matcher.group(0).replace("$", ""));
}
```